# How to add objects to wcf services

Tags: wcf

How to add objects to wcf services?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will get a much better answer if you will clarify your question. It is very unclear what you mean by "add objects".

Answer (score 2):

A WCF service is a set of operations on a service:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface MyService
{
  [OperationContract]
  void DoSomething(SomeClass input);
}
```

You can define the data being passed around into those service methods (and possibly out as return parameters) as DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
class SomeClass
{
  [DataMember]
  string Name { get;set; }
  [DataMember]
  string FirstName { get;set; }
}
```

What those classes look like, is totally up to you.

Is that what you want to know? Your question is not very clear......

If it's not what you're asking - please rephrase your question and make it clearer - where and how do you want to add objects? Add objects to what?

Marc